# In a form, how do you display data from 2nd, 3rd degree child tables that are separated by different relations?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I am trying to display data on a form taken from a table that is immediately linked to one relation, and data from a third table that is linked to this second table by another, unique, relation.

I have an example relation:

[image]

In the above case I have a form of the Customers table. I want to display the Orders data and the Order_details data on this form based on which Customer is selected. As far as I can tell I can only display the fields from the Orders table while fields from the Order_Details table fails to fill.

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Order_Details od ON o.Order_Num = od.Order_Num
WHERE o.Customer_ID = {your_customer_id};`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could I suppose try and display all 3 forms on one complex form, but such a UI can be a challenge.

This is best to think of any ordering systems, accounting systems, or even a system that prints out invoices.

So, you “could” try a interface in which all 3 forms and their values are displayed.

For example, here is a classic “donation” form. At the top of the form (main form) we have the donation event (one table).
[image]

On the left side, we have each user and their donation amount (again one table). And on the right side, we have the “split” of the donation funds to what ledger accounts (another table). So, this form does show a way to split out into 3 ways of drill down details.

However have you ever used any software say like say an accounting program, or even something that makes a invoice?

In most cases, what will occur is you find/search/enter a customer. And once you found (or entered) a customer, then you can then say add a order (or a invoice or whatever), and THEN add order or invoice details. So that second process or "thing" can be your order form.

The issue then becomes do you place a button on the customers form to launch the “display and or create” a customer order, or do you put a sub form on the main customer form that shows each order? Its really up to you. You tend to run out of room rather quick. However, one cool suggest is to consider a tab control, and put the order form behind that tab control.

Just keep in mind that to cobble together such related data in Access, each form is actually based on ONE table. And you build the forms each separate and based on a single table.  For the child table(s), you use a sub form. But in most cases, you find the customer, and then launch another form to say make a invoice (or order), and that form will typical have a sub form for the details.

So, the above does have 3 levels all in one form, but in most cases, it not all that practical (and is hard to develop). However, the above is quite common say in quickbooks or accounting systems in which you enter some amount, and then split out the funds to various accounts.

However, for ease of development, and not having to write much (if any) code, then build a form to allow searching and finding of a customer. That should be some type of “main” launch point or form that THEN allows you to add say add invoices (or orders).

So this screen is for invoicing. We find (or enter a new customer).

[image]
Note  how the invoices are displayed in a sub form. I can hit “edit” to launch a form to edit the invoice (or in your case order) form.

When I hit edit (or add a new invoice), then I get this:
[image]

And, a report to print this looks like:

[image]

So in each case, you build the form(s) separate, and each form is based on a single table (NOT a query!!!). 
Again:
EACH form is based on a single table. The relational abilities of access are  achieved by using sub forms. 
I will also point out that the above invoice forms look VERY crude for this invoicing  system. They were built with Access 2003!!! The reason is that I use this personal. However, the final invoice printout (a standard access report) looks nice, since that is what the customer sees.
I should point out that this application actually started out to work with my palm pilot. (so I would import the data from a invoicing application on my palm pilot).
Then when office 365 came out, I now use a web interface, and it syncs automatic (so I enter invoices on my android phone). However, I am planning to write an actual application for my android phone, but will continue to use this old rust bucket of a invoicing system!
So its gone from 100% windows. Then worked with my palm pilot. Then now in the cloud with office 365, and soon it will work with my android phone!

Note that the first form that splits out "donation" amounts is part of a commercial application in Access, so it looks really nice. But my personal invoicing system is ugly and quite "crude", but as noted, the final invoice that I print or send as PDF looks really nice and that all that matters.

So, I suggest:
A main customer form – you can find, edit, or add new customers.

Once you found (or added the customer), then that main customer form “can” have a “list” of existing orders. Or say some button to edit an existing order, or add a new order.

And you can use a “tab” control, and put the extra forms behind the tab, as you likely run out of room on the form.

The advantage of breaking up this process is you can cobble together the whole thing, and VERY little code is required. In fact, you can likely achieve this goal without having to write any VBA code – you can use the wizards.

So build a “orders” form with the “order details” as a sub form. The “details” form is a repeating data form (multiple items form).

However, your main order part form is not repeating but will hold things like order date, the customer (but in fact it only holds the customer_id).

The “cost” should not be part of the order form, since you have this information as Item_Cost in the order details form. And that means you can “sum()” the total at any given point in time.

If your designs stores the “cost” in the main order part, then you have to write all kinds of code to update and maintain the “cost” total when you can simply sum() up the repeating data in the sub form “details”.